# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3546504756", what does this error mean?

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception, parseint

I'm creating an Android app, and I'm reading some coordinates from a text file.

I'm using `Integer.parseInt(xCoordinateStringFromFile)` to convert the X coordinates to integers, and in the same way with the Y coordinates.

When I run the app, I get an error on that line, which looks like this:

```
BridgeData data = new BridgeData(
    elements[0],
    elements[1],
    Integer.parseInt(elements[2]),
    Integer.parseInt(elements[3]),
    Integer.parseInt(elements[4]),
    new GeoPos(Integer.parseInt(elements[5].split(",")[0]), Integer.parseInt(elements[5].split(",")[1])),
    new GeoPos(Integer.parseInt(elements[6].split(",")[0]), Integer.parseInt(elements[6].split(",")[1])),
    Integer.parseInt(elements[7]),
    Integer.parseInt(elements[8])
);
```

The variable `elements` is a String array created by splitting the current line on every `;`.

The "main" error is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3546504756"
```

I wonder what this means, and how I can solve it.

Comment: 3546504756 is a value which is out or range for an integer. Use a long instead.

Comment: use `long` instead of `int`

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm creating a mobile version of an application that another company has made, and I'm having an email conversation with one of their supports/developers, and they said that they was going to write a "documentation" or explaination of how the coordinate system was built up, and send it to me, so I'm kind of creating the base, like file reading etc. while I'm waiting.

This might be very basic stuff, but I'm young and programming is only my hobby, yet ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error just means that java is not able to convert the String that you are trying to use in your call to `Integer.pasrseInt` as that number is out of range of an integer.

You should be using `Long.parseLong` as 3546504756 number is out of [range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of an integer.

Make sure post that your BridgeData constructor accepts long as a parameter instead of integer.

Comment: Thank you! As said above, this is surely very basic stuff, which I very often seems to forget or miss, and also, programming is only my hobby yet, so I learn new things everyday ;)

Comment: Sorry, but how do I close the question? :)

Answer (score 1):

Revising the concept of data type and their size might help you

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Java, an `int` is 32 bits, which is enough to store numbers up to just over 2 billion. The number you were trying to read was an invalid `int` because it was too big.

I would seriously question the design of whatever you are doing, if you have coordinates with values of over a billion. But if you really need such big numbers, use `long` in place of `int` in your `BridgeData` class, and `Long.parseLong` in place of `Integer.parseInt` in the code that you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The range of int value can be lies between  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and you are providing it more than that thats why it giving numberformatexception

You have to store the value in either long or other more range premetive type.

You can find more about java premetive data type range and value [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)