# Java : convert a String to Int (Unknown Source)

Tags: java, eclipse, casting

In Java I try to convert a string value into an integer, removing the 4 last characters, so I tried like that :

```
 String filename1="98597598684.txt";
 int id = Integer.parseInt(filename1.substring(0,  filename1.length()-4));
```

but I get this error, and I don't understand why :

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "98597598684"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

it's probably sthg simple but that makes me crazy since 1 hour, any idea?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331336/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-int-3546504756-what-does-this-error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846838/integer-parsestring-str-java-lang-numberformatexception-errors

Comment: A solution-seeking tip: in this case you would have probably found answers in far less than an hour if you had googled **"at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString"**. That produced this existing stackoverflow thread for me as the first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935167/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string . Exceptions are your friend, google the living daylight out of them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`98597598684`  is greater than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). Use

```
long id = Long.parseLong(filename1.substring(0, filename1.length() - 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can even try `new BigInteger("98597598684")`